# Proving the undecidability of a language knowing the language of polynomials evaluating to 0 is undecidable

Tags: turing-machines, reductions, undecidability

Knowing
**D={p|p is a  polynomial evaluating to 0 for some assignment of integers to its variables}** is not decidable, how can I prove that **E={p|p is a  polynomial evaluating to a prime for some assignment of integers to its variables}** is not decidable?

Proving that D is mapping reducible or Turing reducible to E would be enough, since if D < E ( where < means mapping reducible), then E decidable => D decidable, and using the contrapositive we get D not decidable => E not decidable.

Is showing that D is mapping or Turing reducible to E the right approach? I don't see how it can be proved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes like you say, you have to show that an algorithm that solves $E$ can be used to solve $D$.

A practical approach is to give a polynomial $p_E$ for every polynomial $p$ such that $p$ evaluates to $0$ iff $p_E$ evaluates to a prime number.

Comment: Would something like "On input p: If p can be evaluated to 0, output polynomial y-6. Else output polynomial 6" work? This is essentially a TM that computes a function f such that f(x) is in E if and only if x is in D.

Comment: No, that will not work, because you first have to solve the problem itself before you assign the polynomial. Hint if $p$ is a polynomial then polynomial $2p$ will not evaluate to a prime unless under specific conditions.

Comment: I am still having trouble understanding how to proceed, is your approach used for a mapping reduction or a Turing reduction? Given a polynomial p that evaluates to prime n, then (p-n) evaluates to 0. And as you said, 2p does not evaluate to a prime. I can compute a reduction from E to D using the former fact, but how can it be used in computing a reduction from D to E? Thanks!

Comment: More precisely: $2p$ evaluates to a prime iff $p$ evaluates to $1$. (Ignoring negative thingies.) This ties "evaluating to a prime" to "evaluating to a specific value".